# Windows ribbon framework: Galleries in the ApplicationMenu

Tags: menu, gallery, windows-ribbon-framework

According to MS documentation, the ribbon framework's application menu should be able to host `DropDownGallery` elements, but I can't get this past the uicc compiler. For example:

```
<Ribbon.ApplicationMenu>
  <ApplicationMenu CommandName="AppMenu" >
    <ApplicationMenu.RecentItems>
      <RecentItems CommandName="RecentItems" EnablePinning="false" MaxCount="15" />
    </ApplicationMenu.RecentItems>
    <MenuGroup Class="MajorItems">
      <DropDownGallery CommandName="MyAppGallery" Type="Commands" HasLargeItems="false">
        <DropDownGallery.MenuLayout>
          <VerticalMenuLayout Gripper="None"/>
        </DropDownGallery.MenuLayout>
      </DropDownGallery>
    </MenuGroup>
  </ApplicationMenu>
</Ribbon.ApplicationMenu>
```

This results in an SC1053 error from the uicc compiler:

```
error SC1053 : The attribute 'Type' on the element '{http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2009/Ribbon}DropDownGallery' is not defined in the DTD/Schema.
```

The same `DropDownGallery` syntax works everywhere else in our app, and the MS docs explicitly state that `DropDownGallery` is a permitted element in a `MenuGroup`.

What gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question:

It turns out that there are two issues here.

1. Galleries in the app menu are limited. The only supported layout is a one-level vertical menu of commands, and the only supported attributes are `CommandName` and `ApplicationMode`. These limitations are not mentioned anywhere in the MS documentation.
2. There is an apparent bug in the ribbon compiler, uicc.exe: It does not allow any whitespace *anywhere* in the element markup except between attributes.

Putting these together, here is the only markup that really works for a gallery in the app menu:

```
<DropDownGallery CommandName="MyAppGallery"/>
```

or

```
<DropDownGallery CommandName="MyAppGallery"></DropDownGallery>
```

Note in particular that the *only* space is between the element name and the attribute. Even a space between the `>` and the `</` will cause an error in the ribbon compiler:

```
<!-- this will fail! -->
<DropDownGallery CommandName="MyAppGallery"> </DropDownGallery>
```